# Oz: Counting 0 in trees with unlimited subtrees

Tags: recursion, tree, subtree, oz, mozart

Im writing a code for an exercise for my uni and have a problem. I'm quite beginner with Oz and just can't figure out why does this code not showing anything but is accepted by the compiler:

```
declare Tree W P T1 T2 T3 T4
fun {Count0 Tree}
   case Tree.subT of nil then
      if Tree.value==0 then
     1
      else
     0
      end
   [] H|T then
      if Tree.value==0 then 1+{Count0 T}
      else
     0+{Count0 T}
      end
   end
end
in
T1 = tree(value:0 subT:nil)
T2 = tree(value:0 subT:[T4])
T3 = tree(value:0 subT:nil)
T4 = tree(value:0 subT:nil)
T0 = tree(value:W subT:[T1 T2 T3])
{Browse {Count0 Tree}}
```

The code should count number of '0' in value of a tree and all of his subtrees that are in the list in tree.subT and in those trees and so on.

I'll be very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

First you never assign Tree neither W so the function will *block* in the first `case` statement. 
Then the recursive call `{Count0 T}` will bind the argument of the function `Count0` to a list and not a tree since `T` is the rest of a list of trees contained in the `subT` field.

The `Count0` function could take a list as argument. So to get the `value` field and to iterate recursively over the subtrees this function should be a little more sophisticated. You could use an accumulator for the count of the fields `value` containing 0 for example.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is useful.

```
declare Tree T0 T1 T2 T3 T4 W=1
fun {Count0 Tree}
   case Tree.subT
   of nil then if Tree.value==0 then 1 else 0 end
   [] H|T then
      case T
      of nil then if Tree.value==0 then 1+{Count0 H} else {Count0 H} end
      else
         if Tree.value==0
         then 1+{Count0 H}+for I in T sum:S do {S {Count0 I}} end
         else {Count0 H}+for I in T sum:S do {S {Count0 I}} end
         end
      end
   end
end
in
T1 = tree(value:0 subT:nil)
T2 = tree(value:0 subT:[T4])
T3 = tree(value:0 subT:nil)
T4 = tree(value:0 subT:nil)
T0 = tree(value:W subT:[T1 T2 T3])
{Browse {Count0 T0}}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).